# How to implemet a session in Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand how sessions work. I need to do a `post` to the route `/task/save` and do a `get` to `/task/list` where I am going to be getting the elements I posted in `/task/save`, the `post` should go with an object on req.body like this `{ "name" : "task name"  }`, and, before I post it, I need to modify that object and put an ID generated by [node-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uuid), then, I need to push those elements to an array and put them in a session with the name "task". I am using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and here is how I have my code so far

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var session = require('express-session');
var _ = require('lodash');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var save = require('./routes/save');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/task/list', save);
app.use('/task/save', save);

});

module.exports = app;
```

here the folder routes where I have `save.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET task save */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Get the list of tasks');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Send body with name, taskName & the modified object including the UUID');
});


module.exports = router;
```

what are your recommendations in order for me to put those tasks in a session ?

Comment: Is the documentation unclear? You have to use the `req.session` object to store data that should be available within the session.

Comment: @adeneo I am very new to Node and programming in general, that is why I am asking, maybe a piece of code would help.

Comment: Well, how do you get the list of tasks, and how do you send it back ?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the router.post hander method, you need to add an array to the req.session variable if the array doesn't exist. It is within this array that you can save your tasks.

```
req.session.tasks = req.session.tasks || [] // set tasks to be a new array if it doesn't exist yet
req.session.tasks.push({"name":"I am a new task"})
```

Once you have a reference to the tasks array, you can store your task inside it.

In your handler for router.get, you'll have access to your tasks:

```
console.log(req.session.tasks) // [{"name":"I am a new task"}, .... ]
```